# embedding a font in Java

Tags: java, fonts

I have a custom font I want to show off in a Java program where the user can view it without having to install it. Does anyone know how to do that?

### working solution

---

I have implemented the following:

```
font = java.awt.Font.createFont(java.awt.Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new java.io.File(Clazz.class.getResource("/resources/segoescb.ttf").toURI()));
font = font.deriveFont(11.0F);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have never done it, but it seems like the methods you want are

**Importing the Font**

[`Font createFont(int fontFormat, InputStream fontStream)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont%28int%2C%20java.io.InputStream%29)

or alternatively

[`Font createFont(int fontFormat, File fontFile)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont%28int%2C%20java.io.File%29)

The `int` parameter is either [`Font.TRUETYPE_FONT`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#TRUETYPE_FONT) or [`Font.TYPE1_FONT`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#TYPE1_FONT), while the `InputStream` or `File` parameter contains the font's binary data.

**Using the Font after import:**

> To make the Font available to Font constructors the returned Font must be registered in the `GraphicsEnviroment` by calling [`registerFont(Font)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#registerFont%28java.awt.Font%29).

Comment: Okay,I got that to work... except it makes the font size 1. How can I actually make it usable?

Comment: My guess is with this method: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont%28int%2C%20float%29

Comment: If you would allow me to revisit this, it doesn't seem to work with a jar file. Do you have a solution to this?

Comment: @Supuhstar what's in the jar file? The font? Or the app? Or both?

Comment: For a JAR file, use the `InputStream` version of `createFont` instead of the `File` version.