# Adding fonts to Swing application and include in package

Tags: java, swing, fonts, awt, embedded-resource

I need to use custom fonts (ttf) in my Java Swing application. How do I add them to my package and use them?

Mean while, I just install them in windows and then I use them, but I don't wish that the usage of the application will be so complicated, it`s not very convenient to tell the user to install fonts before using my application.

Comment: It maybe a duplicate question, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652344/how-can-i-use-a-custom-font-in-java).

Comment: @DanM If you opened a bounty on purpose because you are not satisfied with the current answers, you should clarify why it does not answer your question and/or what additional information you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [embedding a font in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487871/embedding-a-font-in-java)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could load them via an `InputStream`:

```
InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("TestFont.ttf");
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
```

This loaded font has no predefined font settings so to use, you would have to do:

```
Font sizedFont = font.deriveFont(12f);
myLabel.setFont(sizedFont);
```

See:

[Physical and Logical Fonts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html)

Comment: Where do i need to put the TestFont.ttf file?

Comment: For the example above it needs to be in same location as the class file.

Comment: Or if it is in a package, you can access it by the full package name. eg: i have ttf file _foo.ttf_ in package _foo.bar.master.cork_, I would access it through `getResourceAsStream("/foo/bar/master/cork/foo.ttf")`. What this means is: put a forward slash at the start, replace every dot with a forward slash (except in the filename.), and a forward slash at the end of the path **but before the file.**

Answer (score 9):

As Reimeus said, you can use an `InputStream`. You can also use a `File`:

```
File font_file = new File("TestFont.ttf");
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, font_file);
```

In both cases you would put your font files in either the root directory of your project or some sub-directory. The root directory should probably be the directory your program is run from. For example, if you have a directory structure like:

```
My_Program
|
|-Fonts
| |-TestFont.ttf
|-bin
  |-prog.class
```

you would run your program with from the `My_Program` directory with `java bin/prog`. Then in your code the file path and name to pass to either the `InputStream` or `File` would be `"Fonts/TestFont.ttf"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
public Font getFont() {
    try {
        InputStream is = GUI.class.getResourceAsStream("TestFont.ttf");
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
        return font;
    } catch (FontFormatException | IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return super.getFont();
    }
}
```