# Why my fonts are not visible in fonts properties in java(eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, fonts, properties

I installed many nice looking fonts

But I can't see those on my font properties

- IDE - Eclipse 2019-06
- GUI - Swing
- Font type - .ttf files

I installed the Tahu! font. But Still it ain't showing in the Font Choose.
[image]

this how it looks like from the ide:

[image]

Here's what I tried:-

- Restarting the IDE
- Restarting the PC

Comment: Eclipse is not built on Swing. Can you take a screenshot of where they aren't showing?

Comment: Thanks for the response dude

Comment: If the IDE is having problems identifying these fonts, an app. will be completely unable to use them. Better to supply the font with the app. and load / register it at run-time.

Comment: How can I do that...

Comment: Sorry I am pretty new to this

Comment: [Adding fonts to Swing application and include in package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998604/adding-fonts-to-swing-application-and-include-in-package)

Comment: *"How can I do that..."* Do what? Tip: Add @nitind (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.