# Using custom font in Swing to display text in Russian

Tags: java, swing

I am using custom font in my Swing application and loading it like this:

```
URL l = ClassLoader.class.getResource("/resource/template/CarroisGothic-Regular.ttf");
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, l.openStream());
font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 13);
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
ge.registerFont(font);

UIManager.put("ComboBox.font", font);
```

It works fine on systems set where regional settings/language is set to English but for other languages (Russian for example) it displays garbage characters.

[image]

This is how I am displaying name of months:

```
String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
for (int i = 0; i < months.length && i < 12; i++) {
     cmbMonth.addItem(months[i]);

     if(i == Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) {
            cmbMonth.setSelectedIndex(i);
     }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like that font doesn't include cyrillic symbols. The square instead of the correct symbol usually indicates a missing glyph. I assume it works correctly with system fonts.

Comment: Might need [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4487943/230513), too.

Comment: Also look at [`Font.canDisplayUpTo(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplayUpTo-java.lang.String-)..

Answer (score 0):

The font names defined in your markup would be directing the system's cache of fonts and not your application's,this is the reason why your application isn't displaying the desired font(s).

you should try and install the font locally on the machine and use it in your application.